# Geometry of images of maps $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am having trouble seeing what a continuous map $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ might look like. If it was linear it would look like a line but it's not clear to me what happens if it's any map.

I started to wonder about this after I was trying to work out what a convolution of two such maps might look like.

Then I ended up thinking about characteristic functions. These of course do look like just a line of the length of the set of which they are the characteristic function of. But are there maps for which the image is not a line but a plane?

> What can images of continuous maps $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ look
>   like?

Comment: You could use a [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) to make the image the whole plane. One can think of examples for other counterintuitive images - I'm not really sure how to characterize the sets that are the image of some such $f$, because it's a fairly broad category. (Obviously the set must be path connected, but that's clearly not sufficient - e.g. the image can't be the complex plane minus the real rational numbers, even though that's path connected)

Answer (score 10):

The [Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#The_Hahn.E2.80.93Mazurkiewicz_theorem) says (among other things) that a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous image of $[0,1]$ iff it is compact, connected, and locally connected.  This includes, for instance, any closed disk, as well as many other more complicated sets that don't look anything like a "curve".  If you consider continuous images of $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $[0,1]$, you get exactly those sets which are path-connected and a union of countably many compact, connected, and locally connected sets (see [this answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/168086/), for instance).  In particular, for instance, $\mathbb{C}$ is the continuous image of some function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$.

Probably the best-known explicit construction of a curve in the plane whose image has nonempty interior is the [Peano curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curve) which is described nicely on Wikipedia.  The key technical tool in its construction is the fact that a uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous; the curve is constructed as the limit of a sequence of polygonal curves that get increasingly "dense" in a square.

Note that all of this is about *continuous* maps.  Given the tags you chose for the question, it sounds like you might actually be more interested in *differentiable* maps.  In that case, the story is quite different.  In particular, for instance, if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ is $C^1$ (or more generally, locally Lipschitz), then it is not hard to show the image of $f$ must have Hausdorff dimension $\leq 1$.  In particular, this means it must have measure zero.

Comment: Thank you, I had not heard of the Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem  before.

Answer (score -6):

Every continuous map $ f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C $ is a curve in complex plain, in particular a map $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb C$ " $a$ and $b$ are real numbers", is called a path,  which is used in complex integration theory. But about your second question I have to say that no! No such a map has a plain as its image. A simple example of a such map is $$f: [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb C$$                      $$f(t)=e^{it}$$ which its image is a circle.

Comment: Not all continuous map $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb C$ can be used to integrate.